# Magento ScribeJava access token issue

Tags: java, magento, oauth, scribe

I'm trying to connect to Magento using the REST API and the Scribe Java library. The tutorials that I've followed (https://gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/) seems slightly outdated and I can't get it to work with the current versions.

In the blog (and other tutorials), people are using the Verifier object from Scribe. This object does not seem to exist for me (version 4.1.0).

How does one receive the OAuth1AccessToken in scribe Java 4.1.0?
I have everything prior to this working, so I have the request tokens, the user is authorized, etc.

Thanks